# String casing for specific characters in query causing it to fail

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, collation

A lower case a followed by a upper case A (aA) cause our queries to fail when used in where clauses. Error message is:

Invalid column name 'DataAreaId'.

```sql
-- OK
select top 100 *
  from inventtable
where DATAAREAID = 'a04' 
-- OK
select top 100 *
  from inventtable
where datAareaid = 'a04' 
-- Fails
select top 100 *
  from inventtable
where dataAreaid = 'a04'
```

The collation is Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS for server, database, table and column. This is causing a bit of trouble in EF Core, where it is generating queries like this:

```sql
SELECT top (100) *
  FROM [InventTable]
 WHERE [DataAreaId] = 'a04'
```

Which are failing. This isn't that big of a problem, since we implicitly mapped the columns to uppercase during model building, but what is the actual issue here? Can we fix this in MSSQL itself?

Comment: Whatever the logic is here doesn't leap out at me! https://dbfiddle.uk/wqpf-1On

Comment: Can it be related to that: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet#Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet#Ordering)? Quoting: "The digraph aa is sorted as if it was 'å' if it represents one vowel sound"

Comment: That collation gave us a LOT of trouble as well. It merges random letters like aa and ae together and doesn't play nice with a lot of normal code. If you can change it, it's your best bet :D

Comment: Similar problems with cz/slovak collations, where LIKE '%[a-z]%' doesn't actually match all normal letters because z is not sorted last :(

Comment: @colinD - I imagine it is related but why would `aA` be treated differently and `Aa` not?

Comment: @MartinSmith probably because in the `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` collation the sequence `aA` would be treated as separate characters `a` and `A`, whereas `AA`, `Aa` and `aa` are all equivalent to `Å` and `å`. [ref](https://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0406.1252.Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS.html)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  Actually it is still a bit weird because as strings the characters still don't compare as equal unless using an `AI` collation so it still doesn't explain why the "Invalid column name" doesn't appear when the OP is using an `AS` collation https://dbfiddle.uk/7nuuoVq6